# What is the best way in NumPy to convert a A x B matrix into a A x B x K matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say alpha is a random matrix of size (3,2).

What is the best way in Python to reshape alpha into a new matrix beta that has a shape of (3,2,k) under the condition for i in the range of value from 0 to k-1, beta[3,2,i] == [alpha] ?

```
a = np.random.random((3,2))
k = np.random.randint(1000)
b = np_funct(a, k) # <- function I am looking for
assert b.shape == (3,2,k)    
condition = all([b[:,:,i] == a for i in range(k))
assert condition
```

Comment: Have you tried np.tile or np.dstack ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a list with many references for `a` and stack them.

```py
np.stack([a] * k, axis=2)
```

You could similarly create an array from the lists of references to `a`, this matrix will have shape `(k, 3, 2)` then you you use transpose to reorder the axes

```py
np.array([a] * 100).transpose((1,2,0))
```

If you want don't need to have a separate copy for each index what you can do is to use stride tricks so that all the copies of `a` refer to the same memory location. Good if the result don't have to be modified. Specially advantageous if you the arrays are big (you end up saving memory).

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, a.shape + (k,), a.strides + (0,))
```